# System.IO.Compression.ZipFile .NET 4.5 output zip in not suitable for Linux/Mac/Java

Tags: .net, zip

While using .NET **System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory** class the outcome zip is badly extracted on system with forward-slash directory separator.

Reason: The zip contains backslash inside the names

Comment: The zipfiles created are also unusable by 'foreign' readers like LibreOffice (even on Windows) since the backslashes violate the specification. This was fixed in .NET Foundation - see https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/commit/7b9331e89a795c72709aef38898929e74c343dfb .

Answer (score 20):

To overcome this problem a workaround exists:

```
    class MyEncoder : UTF8Encoding
    {
        public MyEncoder()
        {

        }
        public override byte[] GetBytes(string s)
        {
            s = s.Replace("\\", "/");
            return base.GetBytes(s);
       }
    }
    System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory("C:/ABC", "C:/tmp/ABC.zip", CompressionLevel.Fastest, false, new MyEncoder());
```

Comment: You should just forward slashes in your code. It works on Windows too, you know ;p

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: But that will affect the actual content too, say in text files. No?

Comment: No? That encoder is used only on the filename entries. UTF8 isn't in the original spec so there's plenty of zip software out there that is unable to read filenames that is UTF8 encoded, which only matters if a filename contains something which isn't handled by the "native encoding". I don't know what that encoding is, though.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Ahh, I did not realize that it is only used for the filesystem structure. In that case, the solution is fine :)

Comment: My gut reaction to this question and answer though is that I somehow feel that this should be unnecessary. I haven't had the time to experiment however so I can only comment.

Comment: @Lasse - You are more than welcome to check...At start we run with a simple System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory("C:/ABC","c:/tmp/abc.zip") which works as long as you are NOT using it under linux/Mac etc'

Comment: Why does .NET's default settings make it incompatible with Mac, while every other ZIP solution out there (WinRAR, 7-Zip, etc.) produces zip files that extract fine on both systems.  Why would .NET's choose the least-compatible default for encoding path separator characters?  This workaround works at least.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen the above answer rectified the zip issue, but the Linux base server cannot find the root folder, as it exists in the zip.

Answer (score 14):

Microsoft has [addressed this in .NET 4.6.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712573(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> Starting with apps that target the .NET Framework 4.6.1, the path separator used in the ZipArchiveEntry.FullName property has changed from the backslash ("\") used in previous versions of the .NET Framework to a forward slash ("/"). System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveEntry objects are created by calling one of the overloads of the ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory method.

Note:

> In addition, apps that target previous versions of the .NET Framework but are running on the .NET Framework 4.6.1 and later versions can opt in to this behavior by adding a configuration setting to the  section of the application configuration file.

Comment: How can I do this with powershell? I have PS 5 but it looks like its still using the broke zip version?

Comment: Note that it is only ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory that is fixed, ZipArchive.CreateEntry(string entryName) itself is not fixed.

Comment: @red888 In PowerShell, run `[System.AppContext]::SetSwitch('Switch.System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.UseBackslash', $false)` first.

Answer (score 11):

The correct work around for this issue is as follows

```
class MyEncoder : UTF8Encoding
{
    public MyEncoder() : base(true)
    {

    }
    public override byte[] GetBytes(string s)
    {
        s = s.Replace("\\", "/");
        return base.GetBytes(s);
   }
}
```

NOTE: This is slightly different from a previous answer.

The key difference is in the `: base(true)`

This is important or the .NET ZipArchive class will NOT recognize the encoder as a UTF-8 encoder and will NOT mark the correct general purpose bit, and thus extracting the resulting zip file with any other zip program will assume the zip entry name is in a non-unicode encoding which might result in a mangled filename.

The reason is due to a internal call in .NET to check if the custom encoder is `.equals(Encoding.UTF8)` which isn't true unless `true` is passed for the encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier like Encoding.UTF8

Comment: i added this solution to my code, but now  i got a message from Linux base sever as the root folder cannot found in the zip. I unzipped it manually, but there is the root folder exists. Any help ?  My code is   `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory("C:/ABC", "C:/tmp/ABC.zip", CompressionLevel.Fastest, true, new MyEncoder()); `