# System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory - no folder-structure when opened on Mac

Tags: .net, .net-4.8

I am creating zips using
`System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath,zipPath)`. 
All is well on Windows afterwards - they unzip just fine. If I unzip these on MacOS (Mojave), the folder-structure is lost.
As an example, I have ziptest.zip with:

```
A/B/C/file1.txt
A/B/C/file1.txt
```

on MacOS (using context-menu's "Open with...Archive utility (Standard)", I get a folder `ziptest` that contains the files `A\B\C\file1.txt` and `A\B\C\file2.txt`.
Looks as if the directory-separator is the problem. But I can't believe MS would have been so blind to miss this issue. (Although it seems common - I tried various cmdline-zippers and only [SFK](http://stahlworks.com/dev/swiss-file-knife.html) did it right...)
Is there an easy solution or is it truly a MS-bug? (And how can we get it fixed...?)

**Update** to answer Panagiotis' question: I'm on release 528040 which corresponds to 4.8. (Unfortunately it's no longer as easy as doing `System.Environment.Version`, we're back to checking the [registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed?view=netframework-4.8#net_b)...)

Comment: Which .NET version are you using to compress the data? [This possibly duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27289115/system-io-compression-zipfile-net-4-5-output-zip-in-not-suitable-for-linux-mac) explains that the forward slash is used since 4.6.1.

Comment: Good question, thanks! Should have mentioned that - so I updated the question...

Comment: So it's *not* .NET Core as the tag says

Comment: Right - I'll have to check why it isn't. But still . 4.8>4.6.1...

Comment: No repro. Calling `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(@"c:\somesource",@"c:\somefolder\target.zip");` produces a zip that rebuilds any subfolders found in `somesource` when opened with Archive Utility.  You'll have to post a minimal example that actually reproduces the problem. Tried on Catalina

Comment: Opps. Thanks - I'll see if I can come up with a repro. I thought it was a general problem...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Panagiotis Kanavos for looking into this - I tried a repro in C# and that worked, too - so it must be a fault in the development-environment I'm using. Will report to the manufacturer. Glad it wasn't MS' fault.